# Substituindo URL dentro de vários arquivo txt pelo terminal Linux

Tags: linux, terminal

Eu tenho diversos arquivos .txt

```
Ex: arquivo1.txt arquivo2.txt arquivo3.txt
```

Dentro desses arquivos possuo diversas urls da seguinte forma:

```
https://www.site.com.br/diretorio/
https://www.site.com.br/diretorio/
https://www.site.com.br/diretorio/
```

Gostaria de substituir por:

```
https://www.novosite.com.br
```

Ou seja, um novo endereço de site e sem o "/diretorio/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Visualizar o conteúdo dos arquivos
cat site.txt
https://www.meusite.com/diretorio

cat site1.txt
https://www.meusite.com/diretorio

2 - trocar o texto
cat site.txt  site1.txt | sed -i 's,meusite.com/diretorio,novosite.com,g' *

- Visualizar o conteúdo dos arquivos após as alterações

cat site.txt
https://www.novosite.com

cat site1.txt

https://www.novosite.com

Comment: Obrigado Kleudy!